# How to set build .env variables when running create-react-app build script?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts

I'm using the following environment variable in my create-react-app:

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL) // http://localhost:5555
```

It works when I run `npm start` by reading a `.env` file:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:5555
```

How do I set a different value like `http://localhost:1234` when executing a `npm run build`?

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use the `process.env.NODE_ENV` like so:

```
const apiUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_API_URL : process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_API_URL;
```

You would need to have `REACT_APP_PROD_API_URL` and `REACT_APP_DEV_API_URL` set.

Or, if the production URL is always the same, you could simplify it:

```
const apiUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://example.com' : process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_API_URL;
```

Create React App sets the `NODE_ENV` to 'production' for you on build, so you don't need to worry about when to set it to production.

**Note:** you must restart your server (e.g. run `npm start` again) to detect environment variable changes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this approach. Do you think this is the canonical solution for this situation?

Comment: If you do your webpack config "by hand", there would be a bunch of ways to do this. I don't honestly know if it's "canonical", but this way works, and without ejecting from CRA, so I like it.

Comment: We're also thinking about adding support for environment-specific .env files in the future.

Comment: Thought I might work on this but here it is https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/1344

Comment: Something silly that I was not aware of but hopefully may help other inexperienced developers, environment variables set inside of the `package.json` file need to be defined _before_ the `react-scripts build` command in order to be detected, for example, `REACT_APP_YOUR_VARIABLE=here react-scripts build`.

Comment: Hate to point this out but maybe I'll save an hour of someone's life. Restart your server to update your env variables

Comment: This article helped me alot. Thought I'd add it to the commentary here... https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d

Comment: Why should you have to run `npm start` if you're running a build? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Where and how to use latter this `apiUrl` variable. Can you give example how you used it, please.

Answer (score 258):

I imagine you got this working by now, but for anyone else that finds this, you set your default environment variables in a `.env` file at the root of your "create-react-app" project.

To separate out the variables used when using `npm start` and `npm run build` you can create two more env files - `.env.development` and `.env.production`.

`npm start` will set `REACT_APP_NODE_ENV` to `development`, and so it will automatically use the `.env.development` file, and `npm run build` sets `REACT_APP_NODE_ENV` to `production`, and so it will automatically use `.env.production`. Values set in these will override the values in your `.env`.

If you're working with other people, and have values specific to your machine only, you can override values in `.env.development` and `.env.production` by adding those values to a new file - `.env.development.local` and `.env.production.local` respectively.

**EDIT:** I should point out that the environment variables you have set must start with "REACT_APP_", eg. "REACT_APP_MY_ENV_VALUE".

**EDIT 2:** if you need more than just development, and production, use [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd), as specified by [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3903#issuecomment-365096630).

Comment: @SebastianBean It uses process.env from node: `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI`. See the [CRA documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables)

Comment: If the build script always sets environment ='production'. how do i deploy my environment = 'test' to my testing server ?

Comment: @caffeinescript There is currently no way to have any environments other than "development" and "production". 

A really roundabout workaround I have is to add a script in package.json which sets an environment variable denoting it's testing mode, i.e. `build_testing": "set REACT_APP_ENV=test & react-scripts build`, and then have a settings.js file where each environment variable has it's own function, with an if statement that checks the content of `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV` and either returns a hard-coded value for the test environment, or the real environment variable.

Comment: yeah thanks for the reply @user3255240. thats what i ended up doing.

Comment: Thanks for the info on needing to start with REACT_APP_; I ran into an issue with that.

Comment: Also, don't forget to RESTART the app from TERMINAL.

Comment: Please note that you need to restart the server to see the changes in .env file.

Comment: What is the best approach for example when having a deployed version of the code in a test environment and a different deployed version that actually is the production environment. How can I replicate this with environment variables?

Comment: @maracuja-juice If you only have 2 environments, and the only differences are things like how many threads to spin up, or what DB connection string to use. Create a '.env.development' file with your test variables, and a '.env.production' file for your production variables, and then call them in code...see the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) for more detail.

Comment: @Baldeep But when npm run build is run then the production variables get used automatically

Comment: @maracuja-juice then I would recommend starting your test environment app using 'npm start', or looking into env-cmd

Comment: @Baldeep I don't think Netlify supports this, as you can only use the same build command for production and test. I'll need to look into this.

Comment: https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/reactjs-environment-variables.html -> I found this link that describes this answer in a little more detail + the REACT_APP_ prefix. Hope it helps those who are still figuring out how to do it.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env This documentation also helped add much more detail

Comment: If you are going to use the env-cmd if you want to use more than the development and production .env files, make sure you see the latest update here. You need to use the -f parameter: https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd#using-custom-env-file-path

Answer (score 62):

If you'd like to have separate dotenv files for building and/or deploying to separate environments (stage, prod) then you can use [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd) like so:

```sh
npm install --save-dev env-cmd
./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./stage.env npm build
```

Then just update your `package.json` accordingly:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:stage": "env-cmd -f ./.stage.env npm run-script build"
  },
```

Then to build you'd just run this shell command:

```sh
npm run build:stage
```

Comment: Its helpful to have a link to `env-cmd` here, but IMO it is dangerous to have different builds for different deplozments

Comment: @helt Could you elaborate? What are the risk factors you're concerned with?

Comment: Well, if I bake in the configuration during the build, I have to build the app individually for each deployment/environment. I cant port one build to another environment, which will make things complicated when we dont want it to (Murphys Law). Plus, it's quite an overhead for the CI, if it has to build multiple times only for replacing env vars. Basically, I stumbled over [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975735/rendering-an-environment-variable-to-the-browser-in-a-react-js-redux-production) which is roughly the use case I have.

Comment: Those are trade-offs to know about for sure. But I don't think they are the most important factors in *every* use case. For some it may be acceptable to have multiple artifacts for each commit. And the alternate solutions have negatives of their own: additional infrastructure requirements (e.g. a node.js server), or significantly slower container startup times. IMO, this is a question of what works best for you.

Comment: this is the only feasible solution I can see. I don't understand how (using the default create-react-app environment variables setup) you actually create build files that you could deploy to test or dev. npm run build creates build files for production, but that's it, as far as I can see (what am I missing, I must be missing something?)

Comment: @blomster, the alternate solutions that I found were:
1. Use an external server/service that your app connects to during runtime, and the server can tell the app which env it's running in.
2. The container contains the src files and public resources, but not the build artifact files. When the container starts, the react/front-end build happens using the appropriate env variables (instead of the react build happening at container build). After the build, the server starts with the correct env vars for that env.

Comment: You don't even need to update package.json file. Just running env-cmd -f .env.stage yarn build works fine.

Answer (score 55):

Also, it can be done without additional dependency:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "sh -ac '. ./.env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts build'",
  "build:staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run build",
  "build:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production npm run build"
},
```

And have `.env.staging`, `.env.production` files accordingly

Comment: Just a pity that it references npm directly. Would be nice if we could capture the binary that called the target in the first place so it also works when called through yarn for instance, that yarn then gets invoked instead of npm run.

Comment: `"build:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production yarn build"` will work as well

Comment: Yeah I know, that's what I use :-) But my colleague has to add a different one for npm cause he wants to use npm. Anyway, small issue, might be solvable with a TOOL env param or so. not sure.

Comment: How can I get this to work with `craco build`?

Comment: I personally didn't try it with craco, but in the theory, it might work the same way. Instead of `react-scripts` you should have `craco`. Try this `"build": "sh -ac '. ./.env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; craco build'"`

Comment: in Windows you would need to use `"build:production": "set REACT_APP_ENV=production & npm run build"`

Answer (score 19):

install 'env-cmd' package

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start:qa": "env-cmd -f .env.qa react-scripts start",
    "build:qa": "env-cmd -f .env.qa react-scripts build"
  },
```

in local if we want to run qa environment use
**npm run start:qa**

Comment: https://dev.to/jam3/managing-env-variables-for-provisional-builds-h37 refer this link

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Heroku for deployment, then follow this:

- Go to your app settings >> click on 'Reveal Config Vars' button
- Add your variables
- Use them in the app in the same way as you are using previously ex. process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLE_NAME
- Re-Deploy the app
  and that's it...

Answer (score 0):

Based on Chrishiestand's answer `env-cmd` can be used to load environment variables from `.env` files.

```
"env-cmd -f .env.stage"
```

But if you're working on a **NextJS** project (As CRA is now deprecated) the `.env.local` file gets the highest priority and will replace all the variables defined by other files.

Example: If you have two files `.env.local` and `.env.stage`, you can't use staging variables by using the above script since it gets replaced by your `.env.local` file.

To avoid this issue, replace the `.env.local` file with `.env.dev` for development purposes and update the dev script as follows.

```
"dev": "env-cmd -f .env.dev next dev"
```