# Package.json - NODE_ENV to prod/deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm a newbie here with web-development and recently started pushing my simple web-app to a GitHub page. I quickly discovered that my page won't render after I integrated `react-router` with it because my dev and prod URL links are different.

My question is, how can I set up my `package.json` and `.env` such that it will correctly render my URLs?

My `.env` file looks like this:

```
REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL="my-site"
```

and my `package.json` looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development react-scripts start",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  }
```

Inside my `Index.js`, I'm doing this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  require("dotenv").load();
}

console.log("PROCESS.ENV.NODE_ENV: ", process.env.NODE_ENV); // This prints "development"
console.log("PROCESS.ENV.PUBLIC_URL: ", process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL); // This prints "my-site"
```

When I run `npm run start:prod`, I would think that it sets the `NODE_ENV` to `production` but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Basically, what I want to do is during development, my `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` should be `""` and during production, it should be `"my-site"`. That way, my router can correctly render the corresponding views. Thanks for your help!

Comment: works on my machine,  question, did you save the file?

Comment: @rc_dz Yes, I saved it. I also realized I made a typo in the original post and edited it. The `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL)` prints `"my-site"` but `process.env.NODE_ENV` prints `development` when I expect it to print `production` even though I execute `npm run start:prod`

Comment: another question, when calling `npm run start:prod`, are you sure there is no space or type between `start` and `prod`? If you type is as `npm run start prod` or `npm run start :prod` it will run the same as `npm run start`

Comment: @rc_dz Correct, I'm not putting a space between `start` and `prod` I'm running `npm run start:prod`

Comment: can you try switching to : ```"start": "NODE_ENV=production react-scripts start",
"start:prod": "NODE_ENV=development react-scripts start",``` and see what happens

Comment: @rc_dz With that combination, it still prints `NODE_ENV` is `development` :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180967/discussion-between-rc-dz-and-tim).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React-scripts sets NODE_ENV automatically, see [article](https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d) in medium.com.
One of the options is using different env variables, case `MY_APP_ENV`

Comment: I was able to resolve my problem by reading that article and splitting my `.env` files into a `production.env` and a `development.env` file :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that `react-scripts` is just overriding it to be `development`. Here is some source I dug up :O

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L11

Perhaps options you can consider is use a different env variable (you can define whatever you want quite honestly. Or you can just leave the `production` build to `react-scripts`/`create-react-app` since it seems like they have some [internal logic to do this for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42459782/1168661).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Create `.env.qa1` and add build script:

`"build-qa1": "sh -ac '. .env.qa1;  react-scripts start'"`