# change the configuration of an application based on environment setting: Production vs Development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine

I am using React and Node on Google App Engine (flexible environment) .

I would like to be able to change the configuration of my application based on environment setting: Production vs Development.

In Development I have the following setup:
I run my react app in the browser using localhost:5050 and run node app on my localhost:8080
in package.json I use Proxy:
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
API requests use local URLs: "localhost:8080/something"

In Production I have the following setup:
no need for proxy;
API URLs are: "https://www.example.com/something"

How can I make sure that when I start the apps in localhost, my API requests will use the local domain and that the proxy will be used ? 
is there a way to configure it via package.json or via some other option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **.env** files to specify your API URLs.

If you are using CRA, see the answer given to this question: [How to set build .env variables when running create-react-app build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46367006/458679)

If you are using webpack, see this tutorial: [Using environment variables in React](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5)

P.S. The proxy feature in package.json isn't mean for production as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46771744/458679) Because it is just a development feature.