# How to know an app started with react-scripts start is started in development mode or production mode

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

There is some peculiar scenario when starting my react app with `react-script start` on two instances.

For one instance I see the [error boundary overlay screen](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/05/18/whats-new-in-create-react-app.html#error-overlay) while for other instance I don't see the error boundary screen whenever there occurs any runtime exception, though both instance have the same code base and started with `react-scripts start`. I am starting both instances with `react-scripts start`, because I want both of them to run development mode.

I set NODE_ENV=development and verified in app.js that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is begin set as `development`. Still I don't see the error overlay screen for one of the instance when runtime exception. This error is clearly logged in the console. But for one instance I get the error overlay screen while not for the other instance.

As per `Tyro` below in his answer, it seems that checking `NODE_ENV` will tell if the app is running in prod or dev mode. But, in my case though `NODE_ENV` is checked to be set as `development`, but the behavior is like `production` mode since, error overlay is not appearing with runtime exception, though gets logged to console.

Question:

1) Checking for NODE_ENV tells about the variable value but how we can know if the app is really running in the environment dictated by NODE_ENV ?

2) In my case, the app is behaving as in production mode even though the value of NODE_ENV checked is 'development' since the error boundary overlay screen is not appearing though error gets logged to console. Is there any other scenario when the error boundar overlay screen won't appear even though in `development` mode ?

Comment: find a way to check process.env.NODE_ENV, probably expose it to global `window`. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458434/how-to-set-build-env-variables-when-running-create-react-app-build-script?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: But I am setting the NODE_ENV=developement and verified that with echo $NODE_ENV, still the app behaves like in production mode for error boundary, i.e. the overlay error screen doesn't show up.

Comment: How do you set it? maybe you're doing it wrong. How do you check that variable using `echo $NODE_ENV`? isn't checking suppose to be done within your your app (html/browser)?

Comment: I am running the app in a docker container. I started the app by both `NODE_ENV npm start` as well as setting in the environment NODE_ENV=development and verifying by `echo $NODE_ENV.` Still the error boundary overlay doesn't show up even though I can see the same runtime exception error in the **console logs**. The same error comes as error overlay screen on another instance. Please note the edit to my question.

Comment: To help you better, kindly provide a code or more information so that we can easily replicate the issue. And also, what kind of `error overlay` are you referring to? Please specify because it could also be a third-party library where the source of issue comes from. Thus, the problem is not from react-scripts

Comment: I am referring to this error overlay: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/05/18/whats-new-in-create-react-app.html#error-overlay [Update question].

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure you can check the `NODE_ENV` variable used by your CRA app that way. You can't check that in your machine (docker) by issuing `echo $NODE_ENV`.

1. To set = Update your `react-scripts start` command if that is what you use to run your app:

`"scripts": {
   "start": "NODE_ENV=development react-scripts start",
    ...`

2. To check = within your `App.js` entry file, simply add `console.log('env is:', process.env.NODE_ENV)`, start the app, open in your browser and show the `console`, you should see the output of your log.

   or `window.MyEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV`, open the same console debugger and check the value of `window.MyEnv`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply, but unfortunately this doesn't help. I don't know what difference it will make when you do - `NODE_ENV=development npm start` vs putting it inside the definition of `npm start` in `package.json`. Though I tried but no help. I put this `window.MyEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV` in my index.js and when I see in the browser console, I see it is set to 'development'. Still for the same runtime error, there is no error overlay screen!

Comment: So I think you probably need to update the post or title, because it appears that you are not looking for `How to know an app started with react-scripts start is started in development mode or production mode`

Comment: NODE_ENV sets the environment variable, but that does not mean the app really runs in dev or prod mode. I wanted to know how to know for sure, if the app is in dev or prod mode.

Comment: I updated the question. If you have the answer to this, please provide. Else, please delete your answer, so that other can know this question is still unanswered.