# How can I get .env variables with "Create-React-App --template typescript"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I can't seem to load .env variables using `create-react-app --template=typescript` and am not sure what I'm missing. How can I fix it? The `process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL` variable is undefined and `process.env` just returns an empty object.

I am using "react-scripts": "3.4.1"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set build .env variables when running create-react-app build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458434/how-to-set-build-env-variables-when-running-create-react-app-build-script)

Comment: You have to actually create a .env file that defines them. This covered extensively in the documentation, and a quick google search came up with dozens of tutorials.

Comment: nvm I just saw your self answer. Which is fine, but please update the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete answer in the [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) docs about environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It was a false flag. I found out Visual Studio Code was trying to be smart and auto-imported module "process" at the top which overwrote the actual process.env variables being sent through.

I just had to remove the "process" module to fix things. I didn't even notice it being imported.